# Join a table using on multiple columns using a OR syntax

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

So what I'm trying to do is :-

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
JOIN TableB ON TableA.OriginPhoneNumber=TableB.Id OR TableA.DestinationPhoneNumber=TableB.Id
```

Rather strange query I know! But I'm trying to replicate this in EntityFramework/Linq - looking at all the samples I can see a pretty easy way to do it when the join is using an AND (using anonymous types) but does the same result exist for a OR join?

Comment: You could do a cross join and put the on conditions in the where clause.  The DB should be smart enough to use the same query execution plan as a join.

Comment: If you can replicate this behaviour in EF, then look on profiler and find out what query is generated by EF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do a cross join with a where clause

```
var results = from a in db.TableA
              from b in db.TableB
              where a.OriginPhonenumber == b.Id 
                    || a.DestinationPhoneNumber == b.Id
              select new { A = a, B = b };
```

It's doubtful that an or in a join condition would be more efficient than this, but it's likely that either would result in the same execution plan.  Performance aside it will give the same results.

Answer (score 1):

I used `Union`

```
var firstJoin=from tbl in TableA
    join c in TableB
        on c.OriginPhoneNumber Equals tbl.Id

var secondJoin=from tbl in TableA
    join c in TableB
        on c.DestinationPhoneNumber Equals tbl.Id

var result=firstJoin.Union(secondJoin)
```