# confusion with SelectMany in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am experimenting with Join and SelectMany after looking into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36190610/join-a-table-using-on-multiple-columns-using-a-or-syntax) and able to produce cross join using SelectMany (thank SO). I wrote 2 versions of SelectMany that produce same results.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<TableA> aTable = new List<TableA>(){
            new TableA{OriginalPhoneNumber= "abc", DestinationPhoneNumber = "123"},
            new TableA{OriginalPhoneNumber= "xyz", DestinationPhoneNumber = "345"},
            new TableA{OriginalPhoneNumber= "lmo", DestinationPhoneNumber = "456"}
        };

        IEnumerable<TableB> bTable = new List<TableB>() { 
            new TableB{ID="abc"},
            new TableB{ID="345"},
            new TableB{ID="zzz"}
        };

        Console.WriteLine("First Query");

        var results1 = aTable.SelectMany(TA => bTable.Where(b => b.ID == TA.OriginalPhoneNumber || b.ID == TA.DestinationPhoneNumber), 
            (TA, TB) => new { TA, TB });

        foreach (var item in results1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.TA.OriginalPhoneNumber + " " + item.TA.DestinationPhoneNumber + " " + item.TB.ID);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Second Query");

        var results2 = aTable.SelectMany(TA => bTable, (TA, TB) => new { TA, TB })
        .Where(ab => ab.TB.ID == ab.TA.DestinationPhoneNumber || ab.TB.ID == ab.TA.OriginalPhoneNumber);

        foreach (var item in results2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.TA.OriginalPhoneNumber + " " + item.TA.DestinationPhoneNumber + " " + item.TB.ID);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class TableA
{
    public string OriginalPhoneNumber;
    public string DestinationPhoneNumber;
}

public class TableB
{
    public string ID;
}
```

The second query (if ran against database, EF/Linq2Sql) would produce cross join and then filter results with the where clause. Would the first linq expression produce same sql query or produce a query with inner join (based on where clause)? Thank you.

Comment: I would guess that the first one would be a cross join, between table A and a sub query of table B.  But definitely not a join.

Comment: @juharr Okay. So, it is still filtering after cross join. The way I thought is - For each row of table A, it will either (1) cross join table B with table A row and apply the where clause (this would be same as 'Second Query') OR (2) cross join sub-query of table B with table A row (this, I think, is same as inner join). Am I correct?